# Global SnackBar in android

Tags: global, snackbar

I am new to android and i want to implement a snack bar in my android app.as well I want this globally. I googled on it and found I need to create a coordinate Layout for view. then i write like snackbar(coordinatelayout, text, time);

How can make this static. so that my code will be optimized? please tell me.

Comment: Globally????  seems you don't want to create it in all activities. Ok but it is not possible. You have to create it for each activity (layout). Layout on which it is going to be displayed. Parent layout is required for the snackbar. It doesn't works with context. So you can't do this.

Comment: Why It is not possible.?

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you use same xml layout for all activities. So its all upon you.

Comment: I know what are you looking for. But some things need to be declared and initialized in that class. You can put common functions like ValidateEmail() etc in a particular class. So you can use where u need them.

Comment: If we deine any method in our utils, with static and pass a global context  with snackbar, then with className.methodname, it will not access??? actually I am new in android, so that is why I have a little bit confusseion.

Comment: For example you can use toast like this. By passing getapplicationcontext. But snackbar does not work with context. You have to put different parent layout in snackbar. So how can you make common method for this. If you make you have to pass parent layout and msg string as parameters. That is not much efficient way. You can only reduce one line of code. The declaration and initialization in every class only.

Answer (score 0):

I work with FAB and CoordinatorLayout in whole my project so I managed to implement one method static (Global) and it's work fine!

try this function...

```
public static void showSnack(CoordinatorLayout cl, int color, String message,Context context){
    Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(cl, message, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG);
    sb.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color));
    sb.show();
}
```

then call it...

```
showSnack(cl, R.color.black, "Hi snack!", MainActivity.this);
```

I hope it helps.